# Access SQL for sorting by date with TempVars

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

im trying to make a query from the use of TempVars

im Using SQL to run the query but every time i try, it return Invalid date value
this is the line that will not work

this returns error

```
WHERE ((([Table].[Issue Date])>=#[TempVars]![tmpDateFrom]# And ([Table].[Issue Date])>=#[TempVars]![tmpDateTo]#));
```

this returns fine

```
WHERE ((([Table].[Issue Date])>=#10/12/12# And ([Table].[Issue Date])>=#11/12/12#));
```

I have checked the TempVars [tmpDateFrom] and [tmpDateTo] and they out put the date value i need.

Please help

Comment: Did you try removing the hashes `#` from around the variables?

Comment: OMG i dono why i didn't see this before i beeen suck on this for the whole day.... thank you @Nicarus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all or the help.
due to the requirement of the database @Nicarus had the right answer this is the solution for those still wondering.

```
WHERE ((([Table].[Issue Date])>=[TempVars]![tmpDateFrom] And ([Table].[Issue Date])>=[TempVars]![tmpDateTo]));
```